# Java Spring: How to efficiently read and save large amount of data from a CSV file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a web application in Java Spring where I want the user to be able to upload a CSV file from the front-end and then see the real-time progress of the importing process and after importing he should be able to search individual entries from the imported data.

The importing process would consist of actually uploading the file (sending it via REST API POST request) and then reading it and saving its contents to a database so the user would be able to search from this data.

**What would be the fastest way to save the data to the database?** Just looping over the lines and creating a new class object and saving it via JPARepository for each line takes too much time. It took around 90s for 10000 lines. I need to make it a lot faster. I need to add 200k rows in a reasonable amount of time.

**Side Notes:**

I saw Asynchronous approach, with Reactor. This should be faster as it uses multiple threads and the order of saving the rows basically isn't important (although the data has ID-s in the CSV).

Then I also saw Spring Batch jobs, but all of the examples use SQL. I am using repositories so I'm not sure if I can use it or whether it's the best approach.

Comment: What's your question? The title asks for real-time progress, the question also asks for the "fastest" way to save to the database in a "reasonable" amount of time. as well as touches upon Spring Batch. That's already 3 questions. Sounds like you're not clear on the design, which is why your question is too broad.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I started describing my whole situation and then decided to split all my problems up to different questions. My mistake that I posted it with a wrong title. I will change it immediately. But I thought Spring Batch would be an option for processing more data faster, is it not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/shimikano/spring-jpa-bulk) GitHub repo compares 5 different methods of batch inserting data. Acc. to him, using `JdbcTemplate` is the fastest (he claims 500000 records in 1.79 [+- 0.50] seconds). If you use `JdbcTemplate` with Spring Data, you'll need to create a custom repository; see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) section in the docs for detailed instructions about that.

Spring Data `CrudRepository` has a `save` method that takes an `Iterable`, so you can use that too, although you'll have to time it to see how it performs against the `JdbcTemplate`. Using Spring Data, the steps are as follows (taken from [here](http://kyriakos.anastasakis.net/2015/06/12/batch-inserts-with-spring-data-and-mysql) with some edit)

1. Add: `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to the end of the connection string.
2. Make sure you use a generator that supports batching in your entity. E.g.

   ```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
   ```
3. Use the: `save(Iterable<S> entities)` method of the `CrudRepository` to save the data.
4. Use the: `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` configuration.

The code for the solution #2 is [here](https://github.com/cyrus13/anastasakis-net-sample-code/tree/master/spring-data-batch).

As for using multiple threads, remember that writing to the same table in the database from multiple threads may produce table level contentions and produce worse results. You will have to try and time it. How to write multithreaded code using project Reactor is a completely separate topic that's out of the scope here.

HTH.

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to try your suggestions before now. But I think that before using the `save` method, I would have to read in the lines from the CSV file (I am currently using `FileReader` for reading and then `CSVFormat.parse` for parsing the lines to a `Iterable<CSVRecord>`) and then loop over them, creating my Entity class objects for each and then add these to a some kind of an `Iterable` for saving to the database? I mean, it is possible that my CSV file reading, iterating over the rows and creating class instances may be the time consuming part. But I will try the `JdbcTemplate` first.

Comment: Okay, I tried JdbcTemplate and the results are very good. If by looping and saving to DB one by one it took around 0.86s for 100 rows, 4.3s for 1000 rows and 112s for 10k rows (I didn't even try larger files), then now I got those 10k rows read in from the file and saved to DB in 1.13s and the whole 200k row file took 9 seconds. Of course it's 4-5 times slower still than his example (I have an entity with 5 properties compared to his 1) but it's good enough for me :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer simply create a SSiS package that looks for the file and when it shows up simply grabs it and loads it and then renames the file.  That make it a one time build and a million times execute and SSIS can load a ton of data fairly fast.
Rick

Comment: Sorry, but I am creating a simple application currently. I am using JPA repository approach which saves the data to H2 database. I saw that it's possible to use SQLServer with Java Spring, but this solution seems a little too complicated for a problem like that. I just want to trigger the file processing after the user uploads it. A big data ETL solution may be a little too much at the moment.